# Make text content selectable in UWP Javascript

Tags: javascript, uwp, win-universal-app

When you create a universal windows project using javascript in VS2015, it is created with simple page with a body like this:

```
<body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I realized, when you run that code you cannot select the text it shows, or any other text content you may add.

I don't have any CSS that blocks selection, just the files that come with 'Blank App' option.

Is there a way making text content selectable?

Comment: The [User Selection](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserSelection) sample shows how to control which parts of your app support selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your want to make text content selectable please put [`-webkit-user-select: text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) on the child element just like code behind.

```
 <div class="inner">
        Selectable
    </div>
    <style>
        .inner {
            -webkit-user-select: text;
        }
    </style>
```